# Dio no parsing Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I’m trying to parse one object from a Json response. My response.data is of type ‘_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>’. I would like to transform it to the type of my object. So for doing that I use the method fromJson of my class.

Class code:

```js
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:.../stl/store_stl.dart';


class StoreSTLModel extends StoreSTL {const StoreSTLModel({
    required String storeId,
    required String storeName,
    required String subContextUrl,
    required List<dynamic> openingEvent,
    required List<dynamic> closingEvent,

    }) : super(
      storeId: storeId,
      storeName: storeName,
      subContextUrl: subContextUrl,
      openingEvent: openingEvent,
      closingEvent:closingEvent ,
      );


      Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'storeId': storeId,
      'storeName': storeName,
      'subContextUrl': subContextUrl,
      'openingEvent': openingEvent.toList(),
      'closingEvent': closingEvent.toList(),
    };
  }

  factory StoreSTLModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return StoreSTLModel(
      storeId: map['storeId'] as String ,
      storeName: map["storeName"] as String,      
      subContextUrl: map["subContextUrl"] as String,
      openingEvent: List<dynamic>.from(map["openingEvent"] as List<dynamic>),
      closingEvent: List<dynamic>.from(map["closingEvent"] as List<dynamic>),

    
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory StoreSTLModel.fromJson(String source) => StoreSTLModel.fromMap(json.decode(source) as Map<String, dynamic>);

}
```

the code of my request is as follow: (I’m using Dio package)

```js
import 'package:.../app_constants.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:...stl/store_stl_model.dart';



class RemoteStoreSTLDataSource {
  static dynamic apiSTLData;

  static late final urlApiSTL = AppConstants.urlApiSTL;


  //get store from api STL (for now store id is hardcode)
  Future<StoreSTLModel> getStoreFromSTL() async{
    if(apiSTLData == null){
      apiSTLData = {};
      try{
        Response? response = await Dio().get(
          urlApiSTL,
          );
        apiSTLData = response.data;
        print('apiSTLData type response.data ${ apiSTLData.runtimeType}');
        //prints: apiSTLData type response.data _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>
      }on Exception {
        null;
        print('apiSTLData Exception');
      }
    }
    print('apiSTLData type response.data[store] ${apiSTLData['store'].runtimeType}');
    //prints:  apiSTLData type response.data[store] _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>
    return StoreSTLModel.fromJson(apiSTLData['store']); 
  }

}
```

when I try to run, I’m having the error:

```js
Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

so I don’t understand why it is not being parsed. and I don’t understand why the response is of this type ‘_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>’ I'm a beginner in Dart. Could you please help me to understand. Thanks in advance :)

```js
{
    "store": {
        "storeId": "30264",
        "storeName": "xxxxx",
        "subContextUrl": "hxxxu-xxxxx",
        "type": "STORE",
        "address": {
            "label": null,
            "zipcode": "xxxx",
            "city": "xxxx",
            "countryCode": "xxxx",
            "lines": [
                "xxxxxxxx",
                ""
            ]
        },
        "openingEvent": [],
        "closingEvent": [],
        "dayHours": {
            "day": "THURSDAY",
            "morningOpeningHour": "08:30:00",
            "morningClosingHour": null,
            "afternoonOpeningHour": null,
            "afternoonClosingHour": "20:00:00"
        },
        "driveHours": {
            "timezone": "xxxxxx",
            "openHourList": [
                {
                    "day": "MONDAY",
                    "morningOpeningHour": "08:30:00",
                    "morningClosingHour": null,
                    "afternoonOpeningHour": null,
                    "afternoonClosingHour": "20:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day": "SUNDAY",
                    "morningOpeningHour": null,
                    "morningClosingHour": null,
                    "afternoonOpeningHour": null,
                    "afternoonClosingHour": null
                }
            ]
        },
        "eservices": [
            {
                "website": "serviceWebsite - to be defined",
                "linkTitle": null,
                "linklabel": null,
                "serviceId": 2,
                "serviceName": "xxxxxx"
            },
            {
                "website": "serviceWebsite - to be defined",
                "linkTitle": null,
                "linklabel": null,
                "serviceId": 4,
                "serviceName": "xxxxxx"
            },
            {
                "website": "serviceWebsite - to be defined",
                "linkTitle": null,
                "linklabel": null,
                "serviceId": 39,
                "serviceName": "xxxxx"
            }
            
        ],
        "services": [
            "xxxxxx",
            "xxxxx",
            "xxxxxxx"
        ],
        "additionalStoreInfo": {
            "status": "xxxxx",
            "commercialSignLabel": "xxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is model class

```
import 'dart:convert';

class StoreSTLModel {
    
    StoreSTLModel({
        required this.store,
    });

    final Store store;
    
    factory StoreSTLModel.fromJson(String str) => StoreSTLModel.fromMap(json.decode(str));

    factory StoreSTLModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => StoreSTLModel(
        store: Store.fromMap(json["store"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "store": store.toMap(),
    };
}

class Store {
    Store({
        required this.storeId,
        required this.storeName,
        required this.subContextUrl,
        required this.type,
        required this.address,
        required this.openingEvent,
        required this.closingEvent,
        required this.dayHours,
        required this.driveHours,
        required this.eservices,
        required this.services,
        required this.additionalStoreInfo,
    });

    final String storeId;
    final String storeName;
    final String subContextUrl;
    final String type;
    final Address address;
    final List<dynamic> openingEvent;
    final List<dynamic> closingEvent;
    final DayHours dayHours;
    final DriveHours driveHours;
    final List<Eservice> eservices;
    final List<String> services;
    final AdditionalStoreInfo additionalStoreInfo;

    factory Store.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Store(
        storeId: json["storeId"],
        storeName: json["storeName"],
        subContextUrl: json["subContextUrl"],
        type: json["type"],
        address: Address.fromMap(json["address"]),
        openingEvent: List<dynamic>.from(json["openingEvent"].map((x) => x)),
        closingEvent: List<dynamic>.from(json["closingEvent"].map((x) => x)),
        dayHours: DayHours.fromMap(json["dayHours"]),
        driveHours: DriveHours.fromMap(json["driveHours"]),
        eservices: List<Eservice>.from(json["eservices"].map((x) => Eservice.fromMap(x))),
        services: List<String>.from(json["services"].map((x) => x)),
        additionalStoreInfo: AdditionalStoreInfo.fromMap(json["additionalStoreInfo"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "storeId": storeId,
        "storeName": storeName,
        "subContextUrl": subContextUrl,
        "type": type,
        "address": address.toMap(),
        "openingEvent": List<dynamic>.from(openingEvent.map((x) => x)),
        "closingEvent": List<dynamic>.from(closingEvent.map((x) => x)),
        "dayHours": dayHours.toMap(),
        "driveHours": driveHours.toMap(),
        "eservices": List<dynamic>.from(eservices.map((x) => x.toMap())),
        "services": List<dynamic>.from(services.map((x) => x)),
        "additionalStoreInfo": additionalStoreInfo.toMap(),
    };
}

class AdditionalStoreInfo {
    AdditionalStoreInfo({
        required this.status,
        required this.commercialSignLabel,
    });

    final String status;
    final String commercialSignLabel;

    factory AdditionalStoreInfo.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => AdditionalStoreInfo(
        status: json["status"],
        commercialSignLabel: json["commercialSignLabel"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "status": status,
        "commercialSignLabel": commercialSignLabel,
    };
}

class Address {
    Address({
        required this.label,
        required this.zipcode,
        required this.city,
        required this.countryCode,
        required this.lines,
    });

    final dynamic label;
    final String zipcode;
    final String city;
    final String countryCode;
    final List<String> lines;

    factory Address.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Address(
        label: json["label"],
        zipcode: json["zipcode"],
        city: json["city"],
        countryCode: json["countryCode"],
        lines: List<String>.from(json["lines"].map((x) => x)),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "label": label,
        "zipcode": zipcode,
        "city": city,
        "countryCode": countryCode,
        "lines": List<dynamic>.from(lines.map((x) => x)),
    };
}

class DayHours {
    DayHours({
        required this.day,
        required this.morningOpeningHour,
        required this.morningClosingHour,
        required this.afternoonOpeningHour,
        required this.afternoonClosingHour,
    });

    final String day;
    final String morningOpeningHour;
    final dynamic morningClosingHour;
    final dynamic afternoonOpeningHour;
    final String afternoonClosingHour;

    factory DayHours.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DayHours(
        day: json["day"],
        morningOpeningHour: json["morningOpeningHour"],
        morningClosingHour: json["morningClosingHour"],
        afternoonOpeningHour: json["afternoonOpeningHour"],
        afternoonClosingHour: json["afternoonClosingHour"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "day": day,
        "morningOpeningHour": morningOpeningHour,
        "morningClosingHour": morningClosingHour,
        "afternoonOpeningHour": afternoonOpeningHour,
        "afternoonClosingHour": afternoonClosingHour,
    };
}

class DriveHours {
    DriveHours({
        required this.timezone,
        required this.openHourList,
    });

    final String timezone;
    final List<DayHours> openHourList;

    factory DriveHours.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DriveHours(
        timezone: json["timezone"],
        openHourList: List<DayHours>.from(json["openHourList"].map((x) => DayHours.fromMap(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "timezone": timezone,
        "openHourList": List<dynamic>.from(openHourList.map((x) => x.toMap())),
    };
}

class Eservice {
    Eservice({
        required this.website,
        required this.linkTitle,
        required this.linklabel,
        required this.serviceId,
        required this.serviceName,
    });

    final String website;
    final dynamic linkTitle;
    final dynamic linklabel;
    final int serviceId;
    final String serviceName;

    factory Eservice.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Eservice(
        website: json["website"],
        linkTitle: json["linkTitle"],
        linklabel: json["linklabel"],
        serviceId: json["serviceId"],
        serviceName: json["serviceName"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "website": website,
        "linkTitle": linkTitle,
        "linklabel": linklabel,
        "serviceId": serviceId,
        "serviceName": serviceName,
    };
}
```

This is Dio class

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:.../app_constants.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:...stl/store_stl_model.dart';

class RemoteStoreSTLDataSource {
  static dynamic apiSTLData;

  static late final urlApiSTL = AppConstants.urlApiSTL;

  Future<StoreSTLModel> getStoreFromSTL() async{
    if(apiSTLData == null){
      apiSTLData = {};
      try{
        final response = await Dio().get(
          urlApiSTL,
        );
        
        apiSTLData = response.data;
        
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          //Try them, one of them will work.
          return StoreSTLModel.fromMap(apiSTLData);
          return StoreSTLModel.fromJson(apiSTLData);
        } else {
          throw Exception("404 error");
        }
      } on DioError catch (e) {
       return Future.error(e.message);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Try this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).